# How to get logged-in user name in the constructor of a controller in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1 and [Identity 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity). I'm trying to access the logged in user's login name in the `constructor` of of a **controller** as follows. But I'm getting the `NullReferenceException`. However, I can get the user name in any action method of the controller as shown below. **Question**: How can I get the user name inside the constructor of the controller so I can use it anywhere in any action method of the controller. It seems I may have to do some sort of dependency injection for this (but this is just a guess).

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private ProjNameContext _context;

    string selUser = "";

    public TestController(ProjNameContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        selUser = User.Identity.Name; //Here I get error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestAction()
    {
        selUser = User.Identity.Name; //Here the user name (login name) is not null
       .....
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this just so you can cache the username for use in your action method later?

Comment: @DavidG Yes. User name is used in several `action methods` of the controller. So, I want to avoid repeating `User.Identity.Name` everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you can't do that in your constructor (at least not directly) because it's too early in the request lifecycle. You could use an attribute that would inject the value into somewhere (perhaps `ViewData` but I'm not sure that's valid in Core) but if the real goal is just to cache the username for use later on in an action method, then I would just create a method that does that instead. You could even put it in a base controller class for use in any action across your project. For example:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private string _username;

    protected string Username
    {
        get
        {
            if (_username == null)
            {
                _username = User.Identity.Name;
            }
            return _username;
        }
    }
}
```

Now just make your controllers inherit from this and you get automatic access to this property. For example:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
                            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    private ProjNameContext _context;

    public TestController(ProjNameContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestAction()
    {
        Now you don't need to cache the username yourself as it's done for you.
        var username = Username;
        //Do something with username
    }

}
```

Comment: So, if I place your method in my `TestController` above, how would I use it in my example of `TestAction` method above (instead of using `selUser = User.Identity.Name;`)

Comment: Yes, it's `selUser = Username;` Though I wouldn't bother with `selUser` and just use `Username` everywhere.

Comment: Also, because you are likely to use this code in multiple controllers, I would inherit from Base, I'll add to the code to show how.

Comment: Will this inheritance of `BaseController` cause any performance issues?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: I much appreciated this answer. As this is the way I would usually do it myself. I thought the problem was that i was unable to access `User` or `HttpContext` from my super class, which of course made no sense.

Thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use base controller in which you can write your own method to get logged in user username.

```
public class BaseControler : Controller
{
    public string GetUsername()
    {
        if (User != null)
        {
            return User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then in your real controller which inherits from Base controller you can get username in constructor.

```
public class MyController: BaseController
{
    private string username;

    public MyController()
    {
        username = GetUsername();
    }
}
```